# How do I write an on click function to hide everything except a particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="{{simpler.id}}" class="parent{{simpler.parent_simpler}}"><h3>{{simpler.simpler}}</h3>
                <input type = "text" style="display:none;">{% csrf_token %}</input>
                <button type="button" class="btn-primary" style="display:none;">Add Simpler.</button>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
            var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var children_class = "parent"+ this_id;
            $(".jumbotron").toggle();
            $(this).toggle();
            $('.'+ children_class).toggle();
            $.scrollTo($(this).position().top, 500);
        });
```

But I everything on the screen disappears except "this".